# how to create token file from grammar file in antlr

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3, antlrv3ide

I am creating a DSL using antlr. Lexer and Parser are written in one grammar file(say layout.g). Tree grammar is written in another grammar file (say layoutTree.g). Now Tree parser is not properly parsing. I printed the AST output from parser, and its correct. I walked through the generated tree parser code, and found that token value declarations assign different values in tree parser and parser.Below is the sample output from parser and tree parser.

***Parser output***

```
public static final int ARRAY_MEMBER_TOKEN=4;
public static final int ARRAY_TOKEN=5;
public static final int DECLARATION_TOKEN=6;
```

***Tree Parser Output***

```
public static final int EOF=-1;
public static final int DECLARATION_TOKEN=4;
public static final int IDENTIFIER=5;
```

As you can see DECLARATION_TOKEN has different value in parser output and tree parser output. Because of this tree parser is not working as expected.How can I correct this problem?

Is it a problem with generated token file(say layout.token)? This file is empty in my project.How can I generate this file?

Comment: A `.tokens` file is generated automatically while generating your lexer/parser(s). The fact that your `.tokens` file is empty, is not good. How are you generating your lexer/parser(s)? (command line, IDE, ANTLRWorks, other?)

Comment: I use 'antlrv3ide' from sourceforge.net. I have installed it from "http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/updates". How can I generate it using command line?

Comment: On the command line, do: `java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool layout.g` and then `java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool layoutTree.g`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your tree grammar?

```
options
{
  tokenVocab=layout; //NOT layout.g or layout.tokens
  ASTLabelType=pANTLR3_BASE_TREE;
}
```

Comment: I have  ASTLabelType=CommonTree; in my parser grammar.

Comment: sorry I missed tokenVocab=layout; in above comment.I have options
options {
  language = Java;
  tokenVocab = layout;
  ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
} in tree grammar